# Japan localization forcing AM/PM to show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, unicode, localization

Im trying to return the localized form of the setDateFormat of "H:mm" in iOS.

Most localizations would return the 24 hour form, but for Japanese localization, it is returning the string with the AM/PM present (obviously in the Kanji form).

According to this: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns , 'H' would return the 24 hour form the the time, and it is working for other East Asian localizations ( tested Korean and Chinese localization).

Can someone provide insight on why iOS is displaying the AM/PM even though I didn't specify it to show for Japanese localization?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Can you share some source code as to how you are setting/getting the Japanese localization?

Here's what I get:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];

NSDate *date = // some time after noon

[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"]];
NSLog(@"en: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja"]];
NSLog(@"jp: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ko"]];
NSLog(@"ko: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh_CN"]];
NSLog(@"cn: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

This displays:

```
en: 14:06  
jp: 14:06  
ko: 14:06 
cn: 14:06
```

Or using the default formatter styles, and re-running it:

```
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Results:

```
en: 1/21/11 2:13 PM
jp: 11/01/21 14:06
ko: 11. 1. 21. 오후 2:06
cn: 11-1-21 下午2:06
```

Comment: Im just getting the locale using: [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; (also, for my iPod settings, I have turned off 24 hour clock)

Comment: Hmmm... How are you setting the locale for the device?  Are you changing the Region format as well as the Language, or just the language?

Comment: sorry for the lat reply but: I tired it with both Region Format + Language as Japanese and with Region Format as Japan and Language as English. For both tries, it still returned the AM/PM

Answer (score 0):

Check that Settings->General->Date&Time has 24-Hour Time set to ON